# Is there a function in Ruby to traverse dynamic multi level hashes where all that is known is the required key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Is there a way to access `my_key` value without knowing the path to where the key value is stored
using out the box ruby methods?

You will see that the two scenarios below store the `my_key` in different
places. These hashes structure will always be dynamic so you can't predict the
exact path to access `my_key` but the keys name is always know. I've seen `.dig` which is very close to what's needed just with the added functionality of being able to traverse multi level hashes and arrays, effectively like a wildcard.

```
scenario_1 = {
  level_1a: {
    level2: [
      {
        level3: {
          my_key: "here"
        }
      }
    ]
  },  
  level_1b: "test"
}

scenario_2 = {
  level_1a: {
    my_key: "here"
  },  
  level_1b: "test"
}
```

If not possible through out the box ruby; are there any known gems that add this functionality or do you think it's best just implementing your own custom recursive deep scan method?

Comment: The Hashie gem has many additions, including [DeepFind](https://github.com/hashie/hashie#deepfind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [dig-deep gem](https://github.com/hszeto/dig-deep) seems to be what you are looking for:

```
require 'dig-deep'

scenario_1.dig_deep(:my_key)
=> "here"
scenario_2.dig_deep(:my_key)
=> "here"
```